# How to set the data to the specific element span in this case

Tags: jquery

I have got a div as shown below

```
<span class="subtotal">
<b>Subtotal ₹ <span>12</span></b>
</span>
```

I am trying to set the data inside the span this way

```
var subtotalvalue =100; 
$(".myOrderPanel_footer .subtotal").find('span').text(subtotalvalue);
```

But its not reflecting .

http://jsfiddle.net/kgm9o693/33/

could you please let me know how to set the data inside the element span ??

Comment: Your selector relies upon the presence of an ancestor element (of `class=".myOrderPanel_footer"`) that isn't present in your DOM, so of course it won't match. If you correct your selector, and confine it to elements that are present in the DOM, then [it works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/kgm9o693/35/). In the 407 questions you've asked (at the of writing) many of them seem to be about jQuery, and involve selectors. Might I suggest that you need to research, and read about, selectors? Start here, with the [CSS Selectors Level 3 documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".subtotal").find('span').text(subtotalvalue);
```

At least, in your fiddle the span with class `subtotal` was not inside a container with class `.myOrderPanel_footer`, so the selector would never be found.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kgm9o693/34/)

Comment: Thank you very much sorry for my mistake .